# How to create an array from the keys of an associative array?

Tags: arrays, bash, associative-array

I have an associative array:

```
declare -A hash

hash[one]=1
hash[two]=2
hash[third item]=3
```

How can I create an indexed array from the keys of this associative array?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To make an array with the keys from an associative array:

```
arr=("${!hash[@]}")
```

To make an array with the values:

```
arr=("${hash[@]}")
```

Note that you need the double quotes to prevent the shell from [word splitting](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/WordSplitting).